# Solution of $\theta$ when $\tan(\theta)-\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I came across this trigonometry problem. If, $$\tan(\theta)-\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$

What is the value of $\theta$

I got the solution that $\theta$ will be $\frac{\pi}{3}$ by expanding the equation and turning into,

$$\sin^4(\theta)+\sqrt3\sin^3(\theta)+\frac{3}{4}\sin^2(\theta)-\sqrt3\sin(\theta)-\frac{3}{4}=0$$

And then solving $\sin(\theta)$. But this method seems too complicated. Is there any easier and better solution?

Comment: First off, how exactly did you go from the first equation to the second?

Furthermore, the second equation is cannot be easily solved by hand.

Comment: How on earth did you go from $\tan\theta - \sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt 3} 2$ to $$\sin^4(\theta)+\sqrt3\sin^3(\theta)+\frac{3}{4}\sin^2(\theta)-\sqrt3\sin(\theta)-\frac{3}{4}=0?$$

Comment: One solution can be found by inspection factoring out $\sin \theta$ and letting $\sin \theta = \sqrt{3}/2$

Comment: I used factor theorem. I actually got lucky as I took $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and it worked. @5xum Take sin on the RHS square both sides. Take tan^2 as sin^2/cos^2 and multiply cos^2(theta) both sides. Take cos^2(theta) as 1-sin^2(theta)

Comment: @algevristis I kinda got lucky as I was using the factor theorem and I took $\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ as there was $\sqrt(3)$, I gave a shot and it worked

Comment: @Akif_713 The [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) gives the somewhat simpler equation $\,3 t^4 + 8 \sqrt{3} t^3 - 3 = 0\,$, but you still have to either solve the depressed quartic, or "guess" the root $\,t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,$ then reduce it to a cubic and find the second real root.

Answer (score 3):

One good method is to use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)
$$ \sin(\theta) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2},\quad 
\cos(\theta) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},
\quad \tan\left(\frac{\theta}2\right) = t. $$
Your original equation to solve is
$$ \tan(\theta)-\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}. $$
Substitute using $\,t\,$ to get
$$ \frac{2t}{1-t^2} - \frac{2t}{1+t^2} = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}. $$
Solving this leads to a quartic equation
$$ \sqrt{3}\,t^4 + 8\,t^3 - \sqrt{3} = 0 $$
which has two conjugate complex  roots, and one of the real
roots is $\,\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\,$ which yields $\,\theta=\frac{\pi}3.$

The other real root is not so nice. It is $\,t = -4.628884\dots\,$
which yields $\,\theta = 3.567122\dots.$

---

However, if you think you are lucky, then you can find
one real solution by inspection. You can use the known facts that
$\,\sin(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}/2\,$ and $\,\tan(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}\,$ to
get one obvious solution $\,\theta=\pi/3\,$ although his won't get
you any closer to the other three solutions.

Comment: Yes. This is where I actually felt really stuck. The other root becomes really hard to determine. So i was hoping if I missed something or this math is generally hard

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{3}\,t^4 + 8\,t^3 - \sqrt{3} =\left(t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \left(\sqrt{3} t^3+9 t^2+3 \sqrt{3} t+3\right).$$

Using the hyperbolic method for the cubic gives for the real root
$$t=-\sqrt{3}-2 \sqrt{2} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\right)$$ from which
$$\theta=2\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}+2 \sqrt{2} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two real solutions between $0$ and $2\pi$: namely, $\pi/3 \approx 1.047$ and
$$
\arctan \left( (1/2)\, \left( \sqrt [3]{7+4\,\sqrt {3}}- \left( 7+4\,
\sqrt {3} \right) ^{2/3} \right)  \left( \sqrt {3}-2 \right)  \right) 
+\pi \approx 3.56712 .
$$
(There are two complex solutions as well.)